# To remove repository in Debian 8.1?

Tags: debian, repository

I added one conflicting repository by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
```

and now I would like to remove the repository in my Debian 8.1. 
I cannot find it in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

How can you remove the repository in Debian 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--remove` flag, similar to how the PPA was added:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa
```

or 
install ppa-purge

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

then remove

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa_name
```

to uninstall any packages

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

i think this should answer your question.